# Update column values in table based on changes on another column same table sql and php

Tags: php, sql

If i have a table as below

```
Id     value
1       35
2       20
3       10
```

If value 10 changed to 45 so it will be the max value in value column based on that need to change the id to be 1 instead of 3 as below in php

```
Id      value
2        35
3        20
1        45
```

Note: the purpose here to reorder id based on the values on value column from hight value to low value

Thanks a lot

I tried a for loop on value column and select max value then update id to be 1 but the only change happened on one column need to do the changes on all value columns

Comment: WHY? There is no sort order to a table, and unless you use a `ORDER BY` clause in a query there is none there either. So you will have to `ORDER BY` something to get these returned in whatever order you want, so just use `ORDER BY value`

Comment: _NOTE_ If `id` is a auto increment columns as it probably should be, then changing them is not going to work

Comment: Id is not auto increment , because i need to display the id as well not only the value if i only used order by then the display will be 45 and id will be 3 which i need it to be displayed as 1

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using

Comment: IDs are supposed to uniquely identify a row forever. Don't change the ID. If you need a "DisplayOrder" column, then create a separate one for that purpose and change that. Or, if you have MySQL 8 you can generate such a value dynamically during your SELECT query, without needing to store it. Or you could generate it in PHP by using a loop and a counter variable and echoing that.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly i used order by for value column and displayed the id using another way

Answer (score 1):

You could make the table like this with your initial state and have a primary key to make updates easier.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    val int,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

then load your data

```
INSERT INTO t(val)
VALUES(30),(20),(10);
```

And using a query like this (mySQL 8 or greater)

```
SELECT id,val, RANK() OVER (order by val DESC) the_rank FROM t;
```

get the results

```
id  val     the_rank
1   30      1
2   20      2
3   10      3
```

Note the `the_rank` column is the same as the `id`

Then change the value if id=3 to 45

```
UPDATE t SET val =45 WHERE id = 3;
```

Then a simple select would show

```
id  val
1   30
2   20
3   45
```

Now using the query, to get the rank dynamically

```
SELECT id,val, RANK() OVER (order by val DESC) the_rank FROM t;
```

Result is

```
id  val     the_rank
3   45      1
2   30      2
1   20      3
```

Note your `id` is still intact, but the ranking is done dynamically

Showing you dont actually need to change the `id` columns value, you can do it all dynamically in a query. In fact the `id` column is almost irrelevant, except is makes doing updates in the row easier.